# Python - How can i compile python file into exe instead of bundle

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, pyinstaller

Python files are bundled in pyinstaller such that python.exe opens from the exe and runs the file..
this makes the executable with `print("hello world")` to be 1mb+ in size..

So i am thinking of compiling the python file into exe (py to c or c++ to exe)

Is there any possible way?
(please.. don't just suggest nuitka.. because it has some errors on my system)

Comment: The problem of interpreted languages like Python is that you can't compile them to be very small in size. Just a simple `printf("Hello, World");` (with stdio.h header and `int main() { ... }` wrapper) writtin C gets compiled to 17kb on my machine because the standard library gets included, and a similar thing happens with python. You should also consider that converting `.py` to `.exe` usually has to bring the whole python language (parser, runtime, standard library, imported modules) needs to be included.

Comment: @Samathingamajig yep, that's the only bad thing about python like interpreted languages...

Comment: Hello, did you try to refer to https://gist.github.com/pinguet62/d6ad5b51d9964b4fb7f0 ?

Comment: `PyInstaller` can create [one-file](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-F) archives if you want. You can use `--exclude` to exclude unnecessary modules like `_ssl.pyd`, `_multiprocessing.pyd` as they are not used by the `print()` command.